# Python plugin in netbeans manually

Tags: python, netbeans, netbeans6.7, netbeans-plugins

Can install python plugin in netbeans 6.7 manually (without Tools/Plugin) ?
if yes (with .nbi package )  which url can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find one Netbeans that downloaded python plug-in  and go to Netbeans folder and copy python folder. In computer that need to install python plug-in copy that folder in Netbeans root folder and go to Tools/Plugin and activate python .